# MalformedURLException: Protocol not found

Tags: malformedurlexception

What is wrong with my URL, why isit Malformed? 
When i try to load google images its fine though.

```
class RetrieveImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        try {

            URL url = new URL(urls[0]);
            Log.i("url", url + "");
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;

        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("The url is not well formed: " + e);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {

        }
        return bitmap;
    }
```

Heres my URL

```
String uri = "http://c200b.trytocode.com/images/1422684074820.jpg";
Log.i("uri", uri);
new RetrieveImage().execute(uri);
```